# Laravel email resulting in view not found error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am firing an event that sends an email to the user when he requests a password reset.

Here's the event listener that will send an email
    class SendResetPasswordLink {

```
    public function handle(UserForgotPassword $event) {
        Mail::to($event->user)
            ->queue(new SendResetPasswordToken($event->user->passwordResetToken));
    }
}
```

Here's my mail class:

```
class SendResetPasswordToken extends Mailable {
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $token;

    public function __construct(PasswordReset $token) {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    public function build() {
        return $this->subject('Reset your MyEngine password')
                    ->markdown('emails.password.reset')
                    ->text('emails.password.reset_text');
    }
}
```

I have email files (both html and text) available at

```
resources/views/emails/password/reset.blade.php
```

and

```
resources/views/emails/password/reset_text.blade.php
```

It is not working and I am getting the following error:

```
"View [] not found. (View: /home/vagrant/Laravel/youtube/resources/views/emails/password/reset.blade.php)"
```

What do I need to do? All my blade files are in place.

Here's my reset.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')
<strong>Hello {{ $token->user->getFirstNameOrUserName() }}!</strong>

You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.
If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.

@component('mail::button', [
    'url' => route('password.reset', ['token' => $token,]) . '?email=' . urlencode($token->user->email)
])
Reset Password
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent

<hr>
If you’re having trouble clicking the <strong>"Reset Password"</strong> button, copy and paste the URL below into your web browser:<br>
<small>{{ route('password.reset', ['token' => $token,]) . '?email=' . urlencode($token->user->email) }}</small>

@endcomponent
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding how the markdown emails work as I have not had a chance to use them, but your parameter to `markdown()` is `emails.password.reset`. Doesn't that mean your view should be `resources/views/emails/password/reset.blade.php`? You've indicated `resources/views/emails/auth/activateAccount.blade.php`.

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. I changed it.

Comment: Can you show the contents of your `reset.blade.php` file?

Comment: I have added the reset.blade.php in the question's description

Answer (score 11):

I found the answer,
For whatever reason I had closed(ended) the markdown component twice `@endcomponent`.